# Why are my public variables not holding their value?

Tags: vba, ms-access, global-variables

I am trying to use Public variables and my variables are Empty when I need them.  Here's what I am doing.  I have a database app that tracks happenings during a submersible dive.  There are several forms that track things like launch of vehicle, vehicle on bottom, start a transect, take a picture, enter an observation, take a sample, leave bottom, etc.  There are several nested forms with vba code controlling what happens.  One of the things that is done over and over is reading a log with the current lat/lon and depth of the submersible.  In some cases, that log may not be available and the user has to enter the lat/lon themselves in a popup form called "LatLonDataEntry".  They can enter the lat/lon in any format (decimal degrees, degrees and decimal minutes, or degrees minutes and decimal seconds) and the code will convert it to decimal degrees (ex. 30.2345 and -88.1234), which is the preferred format.  I have set variables for LatDecDeg and LonDecDeg to public so that after they are calculated in the LatLonDataEntry form, they can be used when I come back from that form.  This happens in several places in the application where it is needed.  I had read that I couldn't declare public variables in Form modules, so I'm declaring them in a module that also contains an often used function.

```
Private Sub SetLaunchTimeNow_Click()
' Launch Now button should make a new dive note record and put in the phrase "launch" and put in the current date/time, lat/lon from the user entry form.

Dim nowtime As String

DoCmd.OpenForm "LatLonDataEntry", acNormal, "", "", , acDialog

'set the time, date/time, lat, lon, and depth in the splash note
nowtime = Now()
Me!Time_Launch = Format(nowtime, "hh:nn:ss")
Me!Date_Time_Launch = nowtime
Me!Latitude_SITE = DecDegLat
Me!Longitude_SITE = DecDegLon

'move the focus to the dive note subform
Form_frm_tbl_DiveNote.Form![Date_Time_Notes].SetFocus

'add a new dive note record and then set all of the variables to the same lat, lon, and depth that you added to the splash note
'add the note "Launch" to the Habitat Description
Form_frm_tbl_DiveNote.Recordset.AddNew
Debug.Print "Added a new Record for Launch"
Form_frm_tbl_DiveNote!SplashID = Me!SplashID
Form_frm_tbl_DiveNote!ExtraNote_ID = Form_frm_tbl_DiveNote!DiveNote_ID
Form_frm_tbl_DiveNote!Date_Time_Notes = nowtime
Form_frm_tbl_DiveNote!Event = "Launch"
Form_frm_tbl_DiveNote!Latitude = DecDegLat
Form_frm_tbl_DiveNote!Longitude = DecDegLon
Form_frm_tbl_DiveNote!HabitatDescription.SetFocus


End Sub
```

The module which has the public variable declarations and the function that is called when the log is available is:

```
Option Explicit
Public db As Database
Public puttylog As Recordset
Public rst As Recordset
Public spl As Recordset
Public currcruise As String
Public currlat As String
Public currlon As String
Public currdepth As String
Public DecDegLat As String
Public DecDegLon As String
Public lasttransect As Integer
Public transectstarted As Boolean
Public NSHemisphere As String
Public EWHemisphere As String


Public Function RetLatLonDepth()

Set db = CurrentDb()
Set puttylog = db.OpenRecordset("Putty_log")

'move the first record (only record) and read in the current lat, lon, and depth
puttylog.MoveFirst

currlat = Str(puttylog![lat_GPRMC])
currlon = Str(Format(puttylog![lon_GPRMC], "00000.0000"))
currdepth = Trim(puttylog!Depth)

' reset the recordset and database to nothing to release it
Set puttylog = Nothing
Set db = Nothing

End Function
```

The code behind the LatLonDataEntry popup window used to read the lat/lon values is:

```
Option Explicit
Dim lat As Integer
Dim lon As Integer
Dim min As Integer
Dim latmin As Single
Dim lonmin As Single
Dim DecDeg As Single
Dim decmin As Single
Dim minsec As Single
Dim decsec As Single
Dim numspaces As Integer



Public Sub LatInput_AfterUpdate()

If IsNumeric(LatInput) = True Then
    
    ' the latitude was entered in dec degrees
    If LatInput > 90 Or LatInput < -90 Then
        GoTo LatError
    Else
        LatInput = Fix(LatInput * 100000) / 100000
        If LatInput < 0 Then
            NSHemisphere = "Southern Hemisphere"
        Else
            NSHemisphere = "Northern Hemisphere"
        End If
    End If
    
    LatDecDeg = Str(LatInput)
    lat = Fix(LatInput)
    latmin = Round(Abs(LatInput) - Abs(lat), 5)
    decmin = latmin * 60
    LatDegDecMin = Format(Str(lat), "00") & " " & Str(latmin * 60)
    
    min = Fix(decmin)
    minsec = Round(Abs(decmin) - Abs(min), 6)
    LatDegMinDecSec = Format(Str(lat), "00") & " " & Format(Str(min), "00") & Str(minsec * 60)
    Debug.Print LatDegMinDecSec
Else
    numspaces = Len(LatInput) - Len(Replace(LatInput, " ", ""))
    If (numspaces = 1) Then
        ' the latitude was entered in deg dec min
        LatDegDecMin = Str(LatInput)
        lat = Int(Split(LatInput, " ")(0))
        decmin = CDbl(Split(LatInput, " ")(1))
        LatDecDeg = Format((lat + decmin / 60), "00.00000")
        
        min = Fix(decmin)
        minsec = Round(Abs(decmin) - Abs(min), 5)
        LatDegMinDecSec = Format(Str(lat), "00") & " " & Format(Str(min), "00") & Str(minsec * 60)
    Else
        If (numspaces = 2) Then
            ' the latitude was entered in deg min dec sec
            LatDegMinDecSec = Str(LatInput)
            lat = Int(Split(LatInput, " ")(0))
            min = Int(Split(LatInput, " ")(1))
            decsec = CDbl(Split(LatInput, " ")(2))
            decmin = min + decsec / 60
            DecDeg = lat + decmin / 60
            LatDecDeg = Format(Str(DecDeg), "00.00000")
            LatDegDecMin = Format(Str(lat), "00") & " " & Format(Str(decmin), "00.00000")
        Else
LatError:
            MsgBox ("You have entered an invalid format for Latitude or a value that is out of range (-90 to 90).")
        End If
    End If
    
End If

End Sub

Public Sub LatLonOK_Click()
    DecDegLat = LatDecDeg
    DecDegLon = LonDecDeg
End Sub

Public Sub LonInput_AfterUpdate()

If IsNumeric(LonInput) = True Then

    ' the Longitude was entered in dec degrees
    If LonInput > 180 Or LonInput < -180 Then
        GoTo LonError
    Else
        LonInput = Fix(LonInput * 100000) / 100000
        If LonInput < 0 Then
            EWHemisphere = "Western Hemisphere"
        Else
            EWHemisphere = "Eastern Hemisphere"
        End If
    End If
    
    LonDecDeg = Str(LonInput)
    lon = Fix(LonInput)
    lonmin = Round(Abs(LonInput) - Abs(lon), 6)
    decmin = lonmin * 60
    LonDegDecMin = Format(Str(lon), "000") & " " & Str(lonmin * 60)
    
    min = Fix(decmin)
    minsec = Round(Abs(decmin) - Abs(min), 6)
    LonDegMinDecSec = Format(Str(lon), "000") & " " & Format(Str(min), "000") & Str(minsec * 60)
Else
    numspaces = Len(LonInput) - Len(Replace(LonInput, " ", ""))
    If (numspaces = 1) Then
        ' the Longitude was entered in deg dec min
        LonDegDecMin = Str(LonInput)
        lon = Int(Split(LonInput, " ")(0))
        decmin = CDbl(Split(LonInput, " ")(1))
        LonDecDeg = Format((lon + decmin / 60), "000.00000")
        
        min = Fix(decmin)
        minsec = Round(Abs(decmin) - Abs(min), 6)
        LonDegMinDecSec = Format(Str(lon), "000") & " " & Format(Str(min), "00") & Str(minsec * 60)
    Else
        If (numspaces = 2) Then
            ' the Longitude was entered in deg min dec sec
            LonDegMinDecSec = Str(LonInput)
            lon = Int(Split(LonInput, " ")(0))
            min = Int(Split(LonInput, " ")(1))
            decsec = CDbl(Split(LonInput, " ")(2))
            decmin = min + decsec / 60
            DecDeg = lon + decmin / 60
            LonDecDeg = Format(Str(DecDeg), "000.00000")
            LonDegDecMin = Format(Str(lon), "000") & " " & Format(Str(decmin), "00.00000")
        Else
LonError:
            MsgBox ("You have entered an invalid format for Longitude or a value that is out of range (-180 to 180).")
        End If
    End If
    
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: [Debugging VBA Code](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/DebuggingVBA.aspx). Use the Watch window to see when variable are set or unset.

Comment: LatDecDeg, LonDecDeg, LatDegDecMin, LonDegDecMin have been declared as Variants, not as strings. Form Module should also be "option explicit". No form field or recordset variables should have matching names: you probably have a double declaration.

Comment: Thanks Andre and David.  How are you seeing LatDecDeg, etc as variant? They are clearly set as Public String variables.  I have made all of my code modules as Option Explicit but I am still getting that LatDecDeg is Empty when I get back from my popup window to accept the lat/lon values and set the LatDecDeg etc fields.

Comment: I fixed the Dim lines to separate all of the values.  I also put a break point as you suggested on the IsNumeric lines of both the lat and lon entries.  I watched the values of the LatDecDeg and LonDecDeg change in the Watch window, but as soon as I click the ok button and close the form, the two variables lose their value.  So something is still amiss.  I'll keep trying things.

Comment: If variables are declared in a general module header, they should retain value when form closes. Works for me.

Comment: I've updated the code blocks in my original post and this is now working, thankfully.  The LatLonDataEntry popup form had all unbound fields - two to accept the user's input of the lat and lon and others with the converted values.  The user is allowed to enter the lat and lon in a variety of formats, but the desired output is in decimal degrees.  I think my unbound fields on the form were causing the problem because I was trying to use the same name for the public variables LatDecDeg and LonDecDeg.  I now set new public variables DecDegLat and DecDegLon from those two and it's working.  Thanks